# Search performance and process for disinherited security

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search

If I have 4 Libraries each with 1000 documents.

If one document in each of the 4 libraries has dis-inherited security, do all 4000 documents need to be crawled via search now that one document in each library has document level permissions?

This is our concern on search performance.

Answer (score 2):

Incremental Crawl acts on Changing Item permissions. That mean any change in Item level Permission will get captured.

But this doesn't crawl the other documents which has not changed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  So, if I have only changed 4 documents of the 4000 documents in all 4 libraries, crawl will only have to specifically look @ those 4 documents b/c their flags are set to "edited"...or something to that affect.  The other 3996 documents do not require individual security scope checking...correct?

Comment: Yes. That is my understanding. You can read more on this topic http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955(v=office.15).aspx